# Regex Pattern for Proxy

Tags: regex

I am trying to match proxy patterns using the following regex:

```
((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}):(\d+)
```

It is working well thus far, but is not matching the following: 218.25.249.186:80

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of text that _is_ working well? Also, it would help to know which regex tool or language you are using, in case it's simply not supporting `(?: ... )` or `{n}` notation as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This match in python regex

```
>>> import re
>>> ip = '218.25.249.186:80'
>>> match = re.match(r'((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}):(\d+)', ip)
>>> print match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb755da88>
```

Could be:

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the leading ':' or change it to ':?'. your reference string does not start with a : nor does a colon appear before the numeric expression.

Comment: The `(?: ... )` clustering notation does not match literal characters, but simply allows for subexpressions without capturing back-references.